# Subplot size is small as compared to pivot table in python,pandas and matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, size

I am trying to save pivot into jpg format but frame(fig) is very small as compared to pivot table, not able to capture whole frame in jpg.

---

```
Rep              Manager        Product     Quantity   Price        Status
Craig Booker     Debra Henley   CPU          1         30000.125    Presented
Craig Booker     Debra Henley   Software     1         10000.340    Presented
Craig Booker     Debra Henley   Maintenance  2         5000.359     Pending
Craig Booker     Debra Henley   CPU          1         35000.679    Declined
Daniel Hilton    Debra Henley   CPU          2         65000.000    Won
Cedric Moss      Fred Anderson  Software     3         27500.000    Presented
Wendy Yule       Fred Anderson  Maintenance  4         44250.000    Won
```

Data:

[image]

```
    import pandas as pd
    from pandas.plotting import table
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    df=pd.read_excel('Book1.xlsx')
    df
    df=df.pivot_table(df,index=['Manager','Status'],columns=['Product'],aggfunc={'Price':np.sum,'Quantity':len},fill_value='-',margins=False)
    df
    fig=plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
    ax=plt.subplot(111,frame_on=True)
    ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
    ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)
    tb1=table(ax,df,loc='center',colWidths=[0.15, 0.24, 0.2,0.2,0.25,0.22])
    tb1.auto_set_font_size(False)
    tb1.set_fontsize(14)
    tb1.scale(1,4)
    plt.show()
```

[image]

Can you please advice the way around to fix this issue.

I have tried by putting few options but still not getting the whole pivot in an image and also quantity is coming in decimal where as i want that in integer.

1. `figsize=(20,15)` or `(30,15)`
2. `plt.savefig('test.png',  bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.1)`

Is there any other approach I can follow to save the pivot in jpg format so that I can get the whole pivot.

Comment: Provide the data in the text, not as image

Comment: As requested, I have added the data in text format.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to set the quantity as integer:

```
df=df.pivot_table(df,index=['Manager','Status'],columns=['Product'],aggfunc={'Price':np.sum,'Quantity':len},fill_value=-1,margins=False)

df["Quantity"] = df["Quantity"].astype(int)
df = df.replace(-1,"-")
```

To store the table as image, it works for me in this way:

```
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
ax=plt.subplot(111,frame_on=False)
ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)
tb1=table(ax,df,loc='center',colWidths=[0.15, 0.24, 0.2,0.2,0.25,0.22])
tb1.auto_set_font_size(False)
tb1.set_fontsize(14)
tb1.scale(1,6)
#plt.show()
plt.savefig('test.png',  bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.1)
```

png generated:

[image]

**EDIT**

To make headers and indexes bold and change color of text:

```
from matplotlib import font_manager

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(18,10))
ax=plt.subplot(111,frame_on=False)
ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)
tb1=table(ax,df,loc='center',colWidths=[0.15, 0.24, 0.2,0.2,0.25,0.22])

for (row, col), cell in tb1.get_celld().items():
    #make bold the column headers and the indexes
    if (row == 0) or (col == -1):
        cell.set_text_props(fontproperties=font_manager.FontProperties(weight='bold'))
        #only if the cell is a column header then change color 
        if row == 0: 
            cell.get_text().set_color('red')

    

tb1.auto_set_font_size(False)
tb1.set_fontsize(14)
tb1.scale(1,6)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @DavideBrex, Can Index and headers be bold and also if i want to add colors how can we do that?

Comment: see the updated answer to make the indexes and headers bold. For color you mean color the cell? or the text in the cells?

Comment: Colors the headers of the cell with light blue and if i want to color the specific cells of specific columns for say i want to color Red Text for values in Column-('price'-'software').

Comment: Hi David can you please advice how can i colors of the text in the cells of headers?

Comment: Hi, Changing column header works for me, but header of the columns are not coming in bold with this command throwing an error 'name 'font_manager' is not defined' "cell.set_text_props(fontproperties=font_manager.FontProperties(weight='bold'))"

Comment: Thanks for the answers Just last query on this table.

Header have ('price',CPU) ('price', 'Maintenance')('Price','Software')

Can we heading as Price(merging three cells) and then subheading 'CPU Maintenance Software'

and same for next three columns quantity at the top merging three cells and then subheading 'CPU Maintenance Software '.

Answer (score 0):

### This is the output of below coding, it has header (price) and sub-header(CPU,Maintenance and Software

```
import pandas as pd
    from pandas.plotting import table
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    df=pd.read_excel('Book1.xlsx')
    df
    df=df.pivot_table(df,index=['Manager','Status'],columns=['Product'],aggfunc={'Price':np.sum,'Quantity':len},fill_value='-',margins=False)
    df
```

[image]

## **But when i am plotting in a figure with below coding headers and sub-headers got merged in one cell. How can we avoid this please?**

```
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
ax=plt.subplot(111,frame_on=False)
ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)
tb1=table(ax,df,loc='center',colWidths=[0.15, 0.24, 0.2,0.2,0.25,0.22])
tb1.set_fontsize(17)
tb1.scale(1,7)
plt.show()
```

[image: Final Output]

## *I want price and quantity to be at the top with sub headers (CPU, Maintenance and Software) like it is shown in first image.

### Thanks *

Comment: Hi! It seems like is not possible with matplotlib table (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34168611/13328010)). Alternatively, you can use `df.to_html()` or `df.to_latex()`, where multindex are available