# While plotting pandas pivot table headers and sub-headers got merged in python/pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

### Below is the database and then coding and then the output, it has header (price) and sub-header(CPU,Maintenance and Software)

```
Rep             Manager         Product     Quantity    Price       Status
Craig Booker    Debra Henley    CPU         1           30000.125   Presented
Craig Booker    Debra Henley    Software    1           10000.340   Presented
Craig Booker    Debra Henley    Maintenance 2           5000.359    Pending
Craig Booker    Debra Henley    CPU         1           35000.679   Declined
Daniel Hilton   Debra Henley    CPU         2           65000.000   Won
Cedric Moss     Fred Anderson   Software    3           27500.000   Presented
Wendy Yule      Fred Anderson   Maintenance 4           44250.000   Won
```

---

```
    import pandas as pd
    from pandas.plotting import table
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    df=pd.read_excel('Book1.xlsx')
    df
    df=df.pivot_table(df,index=['Manager','Status'],columns=['Product'],aggfunc={'Price':np.sum,'Quantity':len},fill_value='-',margins=False)
    df
```

[image]

## But when i am plotting in a figure with below coding headers and sub-headers got merged in one cell. How can we avoid this please?

```
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
ax=plt.subplot(111,frame_on=False)
ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)
tb1=table(ax,df,loc='center',colWidths=[0.15, 0.24, 0.2,0.2,0.25,0.22])
tb1.set_fontsize(17)
tb1.scale(1,7)
plt.show()
```

[image]

## *I want price and quantity to be at the top with sub headers (CPU, Maintenance and Software) like it is shown in first image.

Thanks *

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34052334/plotting-matplotlib-tables-with-a-multi-index?rq=1) `pandas.tools.plotting.table` does not support a multiIndex so it will return a tuple when it iterates through the dataframe's columns and rows. The pivot results in your dataframe having *both* columns and index that are of type `multiIndex` which leads to all of the "subheaders" getting placed into tuples when you try to plot your dataframe. There isn't a workaround as far as I can tell.

One way to get the table you want is to generate the html code as a long string (without any "\n") using `df.to_html().replace('\n', '')`.

The default settings for an html table are rather ugly so I added some CSS to get the formatting closer to the output table you wanted — feel free to add more changes to improve on the formatting.

```css
tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #f2f2f2;}

td {
  border: None;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 5px;
}

th {
  border: None;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th colspan="3" halign="left">Price</th>
      <th colspan="3" halign="left">Quantity</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>CPU</th>
      <th>Maintenance</th>
      <th>Software</th>
      <th>CPU</th>
      <th>Maintenance</th>
      <th>Software</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Manager</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="4" valign="top">Debra Henley</th>
      <th>Declined</th>
      <td>35000.7</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Pending</th>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>5000.36</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Presented</th>
      <td>30000.1</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>10000.3</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Won</th>
      <td>65000</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" valign="top">Fred Anderson</th>
      <th>Presented</th>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>27500</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Won</th>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>44250</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

To work with python and html together, create a jupyter notebook (there are lots of tutorials on how to do this, but using google colab is straightforward), and include the import statement after your python code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.plotting import table
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df=pd.read_excel('Book1.xlsx')
df
df=df.pivot_table(df,index=['Manager','Status'],columns=['Product'],aggfunc={'Price':np.sum,'Quantity':len},fill_value='-',margins=False)
df
html_table_string = df.to_html().replace('\n', '')

from IPython.display import HTML, display
HTML("""
<style>
// add the above or your own CSS styling here
</style>
""")
display(HTML(html_table_string)
```

Comment: Is there any other way apart from (pandas.tools.plotting.table) i can use to get the desired format?

Comment: Updated my answer. If you're already using a Jupyter notebook, then you can simply copy and paste the above code into the next cell. If not, then Google Colab: https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/welcome.ipynb is a good place to start. You can create a new notebook, and upload your files as needed.